# Firefox extension: Attempting to message content script throws an error

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, web-extension

I have spent all day trying to figure this out and I seem to be getting nowhere, can someone share with me where I am going wrong?

I am trying to figure out how to correctly send a message, from a "background" script to a content script. I want to use `onBeforeRequest()` as the trigger event, so that when it happens a message is to sent to the content script to get some information from the pages DOM.

The DOM part is not present in this example, I am struggling to just establish a working messaging pattern.

**manifest file:**

```
{
    "name": "shell",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.0",

    "background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]},
    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
          "js": ["content.js"]
        }
      ],
    "permissions": ["tabs","activeTab", "webRequest", "<all_urls>"]
}
```

**background.js file:**

```
activeTab = browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true,active: true,})

function sendMessageToTabs(activeTab) {
    for (const tab of activeTab) {
      browser.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, { greeting: "Hi from background script" })
         .then((response) => {
            console.log("Message from the content script:");
            console.log(response.response);
         })
         .catch(onError);
    }
 }
browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(sendMessageToTabs, {urls:["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle"]});
```

**Content.js file:**

```
"use strict";

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request) => {
  console.log("Message from the background script:");
  console.log(request.greeting);
  return Promise.resolve({ response: "Hi from content script" });
});
```

**How to trigger the event**

Once I load the extension, I can trigger the on `onBeforeRequest()`  by visiting the [Car](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Car) page of Wikipedia and clicking on the **Vehicle** part, right under the article profile picture, as shown [HERE](https://i.imgur.com/IrVCtbo.png).

**The problem I am having**

Is that when the event triggers I  get an error in the DevTools console:

```
TypeError: activeTab is not iterable
```

I tried a number of ways to solve this issue but it just persists.  Any help or pointers would be amazing. Cheers.

Comment: `activeTab` is a `Promise`, not an array. You can use `activeTab.then(sendMessageToTabs)`, but there's a bigger problem: 1) onBeforeRequest listener is called with a totally different info, which already contains `tabId`, 2) when onBeforeRequest is called the tab contains the old page, so you may probably want to use a different event like webNavigation.onCompleted.